# What's wrong with my call to message-handler.js in Shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a Shiny app which works fine, except for the failed addition of a message box via `message-handler.js`.

I can think of one obvious explanation, which is if I need to download this message-handler.js file first from somewhere, but the guide I'm following doesn't mention that and when I search for that file on Google it's not obvious where I'd be downloading it from. Thus for now I'm assuming that it's built in to Shiny.

The example I'm following is [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html) (Pattern 1).

My **server.R** script is:

```
# Set options
setwd("tableau_self_serve_portal")

# Connect to Access db
channel <- odbcConnectAccess2007("AD_Users.accdb")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Value of user id
  output$userid <- renderPrint({ input$userid})

  # Value of workbook selection
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$select })

  observeEvent(input$submission, {
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'testmessage', message = 'Thank you for clicking')
    sql <- paste("insert into self_serve_requests (user_name, workbook_to_access, request_date) values(",
                 input$userid,",", input$select,",", Sys.time(),");", sep ="'") 
    cat(sql)
    sqlQuery(channel, sql)
  })  
})
```

My **ui.R** script is:

```
refresh <- F # T = re-pull the AD / Workbook lists from Access DB

# Load libraries
pacman::p_load(RODBC, shiny, shinythemes)

if(refresh){
  users      <- sqlQuery(channel , paste ("select * from aduserlist"))
  workbooks  <- sqlQuery(channel , paste ("select * from public__workbooks"))
  saveRDS(users, "users.RDS")
  saveRDS(workbooks, "workbooks.RDS")
} else{
  users     <- readRDS("users.RDS")
  workbooks <- readRDS("workbooks.RDS")
}

# User Interface
shinyUI(
  fluidRow(
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "message-handler.js")),
  column(4,img(src="leaf-icon.png", align = "top", width = 80)),
  column(8,headerPanel("Tableau Self-serve Portal")),
  fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("united"), #"www/bootstrap.css",
  # Copy the line below to make a select box 
  selectizeInput("userid", label = h4("Name of the Requestor"), 
              choices = paste(users$DisplayName), options = list(create = TRUE)
  ),

  # Copy the line below to make a select box 
  selectizeInput("select", label = h4("Workbook(s) to Access"), 
              choices = paste(workbooks$name),
              multiple = T
  ),
  actionButton("submission", "Send Request", style="color: #fff; background-color: #F15C22; border-color: #2e6da4"),
  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("userid"))),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
  )
))
```

When I run my app everything works except that there's no message box popping up. There are no warnings or errors.

Comment: This is the link to find message- handle. js.  https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/061-server-to-client-custom-messages/www/message-handler.js

Comment: @Bangyou Oh, ok awesome, thanks! I put that in my www folder but when I run the app there's still no pop-up.